# Fastest way to load tablular data from a .csv file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a database in mysql workbench, and i want to load data from .csv files. Now i'm doing with the option of 'Table Data Import Wizard' but takes to many time. My .csv files have million of rows, but each one takes about 12 hours to load. And i have about 100 files to load. My version of MySQL is the 8.0.

There is any way to load the data files fastest? Thanks in advice

Comment: use mysqlimport . its the fastes way

Comment: You might like my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: What are your criteria for fast? Least development effort? Greatest bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Be careful with the values you give to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`, `ENCLOSED BY` and `LINES TERMINATED BY`. Only use `IGNORE 1 ROWS` if you have a header line, containing the field names, for example.

And if you need to store the data on a remote server, you can use

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

You can find more infos [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/).